# Is there any way to mark a function as a template literal tag using JsDoc?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, documentation, jsdoc, template-literals

[Template literal tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) are special types of functions that take an array of strings as the first argument and any number of placeholders after that. When a function is defined to be used for template literals, it's typically only used for that purpose, since it's a pretty specific form of function.

Is there any tag or preferred method to mark a function as such using JsDoc?

Here's an example of such a function:

```
/**
 * What goes here?
 */
function withoutWhiteSpace(strings, ...placeholders) {
  let withSpace = strings.reduce((result, string, i) => (
    result + placeholders[i - 1] + string
  ));
  let withoutSpace = withSpace.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
  return withoutSpace;
}

let lines = 3;
let exampleString = withoutWhiteSpace`This is a string created with the template
    literal syntax. It's really long and stretches over ${lines} lines, so a tag
    is used to remove line breaks and whitespace.`
// exampleString = "This is a string created with the template literal syntax. It's really long and stretches over 3 lines, so a tag is used to remove line breaks and whitespace."
```

Comment: Good question! I post an issue here: https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1682

Comment: I'm getting a `'html' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)` when I use [a tag function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) called [`html`](https://github.com/developit/htm). Example: ``(role) => html`<option value=${role.value}>${role.name}</option>` `` pukes. Did you find a solution for this?